# Updating Jinja2 Variables every X seconds - Python Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to update variables inside of my index.html file. I am going to be running a thread with a loop in python but I want a way to update my jinja2 table listed below to update every x seconds just like if you were using php and ajax.

Here is my Jinja2 Code:

```
<table border=1 id="allTable" class="display">
        <tbody id="eliteTable">
        <tr><td colspan=9 class=queueheader>Elite  (Current SLA: {{ eliteSLA | safe}}%)</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Skill</th><th>SLA</th><th>Calls Waiting</th><th>Hold Time</th><th>Staffed</th><th>Avail</th><th>ACW</th><th>Aux</th><th>ACD Calls</th></tr>
        {% for row in eliteList %}
            {% if row[2]|int > 30 %}
                <tr class=longwait>
            {% elif row[2]|int > 0 %}
                <tr class=waiting>
            {% else %}
                <tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% for i in row %}
                <td> {{ i | safe }} </td>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

Comment: and where is your question?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need some javascript in there.

Either ajax requests, or websockets, though ajax might be simpler.

Simply use javascript `setInterval()` with an ajax request.

I'd recommend using a library, maybe jquery as it is very simple.

```
$.get( "/auto_refresh", function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

Note that jinja2 is just for the templating, meaning that at some point the jinja templates get translated into html/css.
So you can play with ajax like you did when you were using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Jinja variables are generated at template render-time. There's no way to programmatically update them without using javascript of some sort.

From [the docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/) (emphasis mine):

> A [Jinja] template contains variables and/or expressions, **which get replaced with values when a template is rendered**; and tags, which control the logic of the template. The template syntax is heavily inspired by Django and Python.